# Django save previous object from models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

In a Django admin site, I have this class.
I want to save a previous version of a object (Servers) which is a manytomany field to find changes on the object.

With normal CharField this work, but for manytomany fields I got this error:

```
"<SourceDestinationGroup: asdas>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

here is my objectclass

```
class SourceDestinationGroup(models.Model):
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        ('C', 'in Change'),
        ('F', 'Finished')
        )
    ServerGroupName = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True)
    Servers = models.ManyToManyField(Server)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default='C')



    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(SourceDestinationGroup, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self._old_Servers = self.Servers

    def save(self, **kw):
       if self.Servers != self._old_Servers:
            self.Status = 'C'
            self._old_Servers = self.Servers

        super(SourceDestinationGroup, self).save(**kw)



   def __str__(self):
       return self.ServerGroupName
```

Comment: Please, include full stack trace in your question

Comment: sorry I had changed the code so now I receive other Errors.

Comment: While debuging i detect that the change of m2m affect on next save on the site. Thats quiet strange. I can change stuff in the m2m object but I see the changes on the second save.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace still.

Comment: I solved the problem. The Problem was that m2m objects don't update theyself in the save methode. Using  'm2m_changed' worked well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M2M relationships aren't saved as part of the save() method.
In the admin, the main object is saved, and then the m2m relation is saved; so, by serializing the list of tags in the save method, you're printing the value of the tags before the new values have been saved. 
If you want to install "post m2m save" behavior, you'd need to override the update view on the admin itself.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to initialize the ManyToMany attribute (.Servers) when creating the object..

Wherever you try to create the SourceDestinationGroup, you should probably create it **THEN** do:

```
group.Servers = servers
group.save()
```

Or, **remove** the Servers attribute in the init method and reset it afterwards:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super(SourceDestinationGroup, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
    self._temp_Servers = self.Servers

def save(self, **kw):
    if self.id is None:
        self._temp_Servers = self.Servers
        self.Servers = None # Your 'Servers' attribute was still being set, hence raising an Exception in the super.save just after
    super(SourceDestinationGroup, self).save(**kw)
    if self._old_Servers is not None:
        self.Servers = self._temp_Servers 
        super(SourceDestinationGroup, self).save(**kw)
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem a few month ago. The m2m relationships are not updated inside the model `save` method, even if `super()` is called before using those relationships.

The only workaround I've found is to write a separate function that deals with m2m relationships, and call it from the `save` method of the **form**:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    instance.update_m2m()
    return instance
```

In your case, this function is the nearly the same as your model `save` method:

```
def update_m2m(self):
    if self.Servers != self._old_Servers:
       self.Status = 'C'
       self._old_Servers = self.Servers
       self.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SourceDestinationGroup` instance must be saved to database **before** you can add any servers to it. You probably can do an easy fix to it in your `save` method:

```
def save(self, **kw):
    if self.id is not None and self.Servers != self._old_Servers:
        self.Status = 'C'
        self._old_Servers = self.Servers

    super(SourceDestinationGroup, self).save(**kw)
```

As I can see, your change of server only makes sense when there are any old values.

Comment: Thx for that advice. I tried this but the errormsg is the same. I think the Problem starts with the init function.